# Raspberry Pi 4 as Thin client for low traffic program (http requests)

Tags: networking

My setup is: 
A Smart plug (Tp link HS 110), 
A Raspberry Pi 4B

What I already achieved/main project:
The Smartplug is connected to my TV, when my TV is turned on and the power consumption through the Smartplug surpasses a specific threshold, a http Request should be sent. If the tv is turned off, another http request should be sent. I have a node red network running on my Raspberry that is monitoring the power consumption of the smartplug and does the http request stuff. I wrote a Node js Script that does a local network search and finds the ip adress of the smartplug so Node red can use it later on, and a server is setup on the raspberry pi.

But now, I want to change my Raspberry somehow to a thin client. Its only Job should be to find the smart plug with the local network search (mac adress of the smartplug is provided) once if it is set up, and then just write all data that it collects to a server, maybe an aws Lambda server (not sure if this would work) or if easier it should write the data in a influx database hosted on aws. 
Then I want the server to figure out, if any threshold is surpassed, and if so, to send the http request.

So basically my question is: 
How can I turn my Raspberry to a thin client, that is able to execute a node.js script which only needs to ask the user stuff like "Mac adress of your smart plug?". and then sets up a connection to amazon lambda or an influx db or something. I didnt figure out where I should start yet.

There seem to be some possibilities to turn your raspberry into a thin client, but some of them seem to have a monthly pay plan, or whatever.

Im free for any suggestions on how to start digging into this, since my thin client actually needs to do very little stuff and I hope it can be achieved somehow.

Best regards,
Michael

Comment: why would you want to use a raspberry pi for such a "dumb" task? let alone a raspberry pi 4!! it's like using a sledgehammer to put a thumb tack into a noticeboard!

Comment: What else can you recommend for that task?
I just have that Raspberry right now. If I can create the infrastructure now on my Raspberry I can later use a smaller computer, probably raspberry zero or something.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with using any Pi for a task like this.  Yes, the Pi is a bit overpowered than say a Pi Zero W but if that's all you have, go for it.

Comment: To argue semantics a bit: I think "thin client" is a bit of a misnomer here, ie., what you are describing is either not truly a thin client, or a thin client is not necessary and pursuing it as such is a wrong turn.  By analogy, a device which provides just a web browser might be considered a thin client, but not every device that provides a web browser is a thin client although they may do identical SaaS interactions. **If you want to offload work to AWS, just do it.**  You do not need to modify the system in some fundamental way to make it "thinner".